# Laravel 5.2 Inserting and updating data from dynamic form

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, bulkinsert

So far, I have found answers in here and never needed to ask anything. But this issue is really bugging me. Here is the situation. I have a dynamic invoice form. Posts from the form will be saved to two different tables

1. invoices(where details for invoice is stored like member_id, discount, duedate, remarks and the timestamps)
2. invoiceitems(invoice_id, itemdescription, quantity, rate, timestamps)

To achieve this, here is my method to store invoice

```
public function store(InvoiceRequest $request)
{

//get necessary details for invoice table
$datainvoice = array(
'member_id' => $request->input('member_id'),
'duedate' => $request->input('duedate'),
'discount' => $request->input('discount'),
'remarks' => $request->input('remarks'),
//'gtotal' => $request->input ('gtotal'),
);

//save result of invoice
$resultforinvoice = Invoice::create($datainvoice);


// ready all data of invoice items
$datainvoiceitem = array(
'description' => $request->input('description'),
'rate' => $request->input('rate'),
'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
'invoice_id' => $resultforinvoice->id,
);


 // insert invoice along with invoice_id
Invoiceitem::create($datainvoiceitem);
return redirect('members');

}
```

**Additional Information:**

Relationship between members and invoices:: member-has-many-invoices, invoice-belongs-to-single-member

Relationship between invoice and invoiceitems:: invoice-has-many-items, 
an-item-belongs-to-one-invoice

partial of the dynamic form:

```
<td>  1   </td>
<td><textarea type="text" name='description[0][description]'   class="form-control"/></textarea> </td>
<td><input type="text" name='quantity[0][quantity]'  class="form-control"/></td>
<td> <input type="text" name='rate[0][rate]'  class="form-control"/>   </td>
```

Errors im receiving right now Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\study\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 719 and defined

**Update**

when i try to return the inputs for invoiceitems to check whats going on, i get an array like below

```
{
"description": [
{
    "description": "desc1"
},
{
    "description": "desc2"
}
],
"rate": [
{
    "rate": "11"
},
{
    "rate": "22"
}
],
"quantity": [
{
    "quantity": "1"
},
{
    "quantity": "2"
}
],
"invoice_id": 41

}
```

Guys, please tell let me know where im missing. I have tried asking this in laracast as well, its been couple of hours nothing at the moment, hopefully someone will point me to right direction.  [Here is the laracast link.](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/inserting-and-updating-data-from-dynamic-form-properly)

Comment: According to your input names `$request->input('description')` returns an array instead a single value. And after that you try to save this array as column value. I'm not sure, but I think that this your problem.

Comment: @Phargelm Im trying to get this sorted using transpose(), i will keep this updated once i have a functioning code

Comment: @Phargelm im following a tutorial [link](https://adamwathan.me/2016/04/06/cleaning-up-form-input-with-transpose/) Now, im getting the array properly but i want to add extra information, say invoice_id in the array. Would you point me into right direction. Im updating my stuffs here, [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/inserting-and-updating-data-from-dynamic-form-properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up updating majority of the code and now it looks like this

```
 $items = [];
    foreach ($request->items as $field => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
            $items[$index][$field] = $value;
        }
    }


    Invoice::create($invoice)
        ->invoiceitem()->createMany($items);
```

and it just worked. Let me know anyone else needs help with this. I would be happy to explain

Comment: This is how i did it!
`foreach($items as $item) {

            $invoice->invoiceitem()->updateOrCreate(['id'=> $item['id']],$item);
      
 }`

Comment: And what if you delete some old ones and add new ones

Comment: @ashish Can you help me on this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540484/update-data-into-table-from-dynamically-created-input-field/44542622?noredirect=1#comment76078383_44542622]. I'm able to insert new rows but unable to update it.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest

```
public function store(InvoiceRequest $request)
{
    $invoice_fields = ['member_id', 'duedate', 'discount', 'remarks', 'gtotal'];

    $items = [];

    foreach ($request->items as $field => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
            $items[$index][$field] = $value;
        }
    }        

    Invoice::create($request->only($invoice_fields))
        ->items()->createMany($items);

    return redirect('members');    
}
```

(If you set up the relation properly, you don't need to manually assign the invoice_id to each item, just have the Invoice `create` the Item).

---

You may abstract the `foreach`s into a separate method, a Collection macro may be a good idea as the tutorial suggests (although I implement it differently; my suggestion doesn't need index numbers in the original HTML).
The HTML for your form should look like

```
<input type="text" name="items[description][]">
<input type="text" name="items[quantity][]">
<input type="text" name="items[rate][]">

<input type="text" name="items[description][]">   <!-- as many of --> 
<input type="text" name="items[quantity][]">      <!-- these      -->
<input type="text" name="items[rate][]">          <!-- as needed  -->
```

Comment: This would really simplify whole thing, updating the form would be much simpler but one thing, since we are using the name form form fields as items[description][], without indexing, how do we validate the form? Can you give me some idea?

Comment: NEVER MIND!! SOLVED IT :P im gonna post whole thing when im done!!