# Update data into table from dynamically created input field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have 2 models **Tour.php**

```
public function Itinerary()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Itinerary', 'tour_id');
}
```

**and**

**Itinerary.php**

```
public function tour() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour', 'tour_id');
}
```

**tours** table:

`id|title|content`

**itineraries** table:

`id|tour_id|day|itinerary`

I have used vue js to create or add and remove input field for day and plan dynamically. And used the following code in `tour.store` method to insert into `itineraries` table:

```
    $count = count($request->input('day'));
$temp_day        = $request->input('day');
$temp_itinerary  =   $request->input('itinerary');

for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) 
{

    $itinerary = new Itinerary;
    $itinerary->tour_id        =  $tour->id;
    $itinerary->plan      =   $temp_itinerary[$i];        
    $itinerary->day            =   $temp_day[$i];
    $itinerary->save();
}
```

And was successful in inserting the records.And applied same code in `tour.store` method. Instead of updating the rows, it inserted new rows to the table. What would be the best solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

For updation try this code

```
$itinerary = Itinerary::find($tour_id);
$itinerary->plan = $temp_itinerary[$i];        
$itinerary->day = $temp_day[$i];
$itinerary->save();
```

Comment: Your code is also doing the same thing. Adding new rows instead of updating it. FYI I used your code with and without for loop and result was same.

Comment: The line `$itinerary = Itinerary::find($tour_id);` is returning error `Creating default object from empty value`. I have assigned `$tour_id = $tour->id;` before start of the for loop.

Comment: Is there any way you use builder query instead of eloquent?

Comment: Is it impossible to do by eloquent method ?

Comment: No its not impossible I am just asking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146638/discussion-between-rahul-and-tanja-forsberg).

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using is to insert/create new records. To update you can use.

```
Itinerary::find($tour_id)->update(
   ['column_name'=> value]
);
```

Where `find` method takes a primary key of the table.

This will update your existing record. You can update as many columns as you want just pass in array `update` takes. You can also use `save` method as mentioned in other answer.

Check [Laravel Update Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates)

**EDIT**

```
$iterneary = Itenerary::where('tour_id', $tour_id)->first();
```

Now you can update this `iterneary` object to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Your code was returning message `Call to a member function update() on null`. So I tried `$test = Itinerary::find($tour_id);
       dd($test);
where $tour_id = $tour->id; i.e tour_id =2;` The output was `null` . Don't know what the heck is going on.

Comment: @TanjaForsberg, please check the edit above and do `dd($iterneary)` before moving further.

Comment: Still no luck. The code is still adding new rows instead of updating records.

Comment: I'm running this code `$itinerary = Itinerary::where('tour_id', $tour_id);
        for($i = 0; $i <$count; ++$i) 
        {
            $itinerary->updateOrCreate([
                'tour_id' => $tour_id,
                'plan' => $temp_itinerary[$i],
                'day' => $temp_day[$i],
                ]);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did it. First saved all the tours in $tours[] array.

```
foreach($tours as $tour) {
        $itinerary->tour()->updateOrCreate(['id'=> $tour['id']],$tour);
    }
```

updateOrCreate because you may need to add new tours while updating. I know this doesnt answer your issue exactly but this could atleast give you an idea.